# 14 Bit conversion in HEX - MCP2515 and MAX31855

Tags: c++, arduino, hex

Referring to the MAX31855 board, the signed value of the temperature is given by 14bits bits [31:18].
Those 14 bits are sent out MSB first, and the first bit is the sign bit.

Those are the example values:

[Temperature data format](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/47368290/91191912-a2260c80-e6f5-11ea-8864-afe58eb10d47.PNG)

I would like to place the value in the first two slot of a 8 slot array, that will be sent out via CAN with a MCP2515 module.

Actually i'm studying this code, that is the send example of the MCP_CAN_lib:
[Library](https://github.com/coryjfowler/MCP_CAN_lib)

```cpp
// CAN Send Example
//

#include <mcp_can.h>
#include <SPI.h>

MCP_CAN CAN0(10);     // Set CS to pin 10

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize MCP2515 running at 16MHz with a baudrate of 500kb/s and the masks and filters disabled.
  if(CAN0.begin(MCP_ANY, CAN_500KBPS, MCP_16MHZ) == CAN_OK) Serial.println("MCP2515 Initialized Successfully!");
  else Serial.println("Error Initializing MCP2515...");

  CAN0.setMode(MCP_NORMAL);   // Change to normal mode to allow messages to be transmitted
}

byte data[8] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07};

void loop()
{
  // send data:  ID = 0x100, Standard CAN Frame, Data length = 8 bytes, 'data' = array of data bytes to send
  byte sndStat = CAN0.sendMsgBuf(0x100, 0, 8, data);
  if(sndStat == CAN_OK){
    Serial.println("Message Sent Successfully!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Error Sending Message...");
  }
  delay(100);   // send data per 100ms
}

/*********************************************************************************************************
  END FILE
*********************************************************************************************************/
```

Any help, and suggestion about best libraries to use, is appreciated!

Comment: Is your question - how to place 14 bits into two bytes? What is the layout you need? 8 lower bits in the second byte and 6 high bits (sign-extended) in the first?

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic.  And woefully unnecessary in this simple case.

Comment: @vlad I’ll try to be more clear about my need. I have to get the value that I’m already getting from the sensor, already converted in decimal format and “put” the value in the first two bytes of the can massage. This will allow me to put up to 4 different sensor on one message. This on the sender side, on the receiver side, I have to “decode” the message and split the 4 results.  Something like this 00 00 | 00 00 | 00 00 | 00 00 —> value 1| value 2 | value 3 | value 4. I’m also using the MAX31855 library from Rob Tillaard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you mean by "already converted in decimal format" and why would you need that.

Here is how you can shift the the value from the board and put it into first two bytes of your array (fr your 1,000C example):

```
unsigned char data[8] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07 };
int temp = 0b0011'1110'1000'0000'0000'0000'0000'0000;
temp >>= 18;
data[1] = temp & 0xFF;
temp >>= 8;
data[0] = temp & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Hello Vlad, thank you for your answer.
Please have a look to the open issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/FabioBrondo/Multiple-MAX31855/issues/4

There you can find all the infos, and refer to libraries, code already used etc...

Comment: Anyway, what i want to do is to use the slot of the array in this way:

byte data[8] = {0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07};
0x00 and 0x01 = Channel 1
0x02 and 0x03 = Channel 2
0x04 and 0x05 = Channel 3
0x06 and 0x07 = Channel 4 
I'm getting the rawData from the libray of @RobTillaart: https://github.com/RobTillaart/MAX31855_RT

As told, i want to send the value out from one MCP2515 module and "decode" the value on an other MCP2515.

Maybe this can help to better understand the question...